# Trying to run multiple processes in bash only executes one time

Tags: bash, for-loop, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

I have the following in my bash file:

```
echo "Spawning $1 processes"
for i in {1..$1}
do
    (go run loadgen.go $2 &)
    echo "done."
done
```

However, I can only seem to get my go file to execute once. I know that they're started in the background, but each of my go files should append to the same log file (I can reproduce this by running my bash script multiple times). Am I doing something wrong to get this to iterate multiple times?

Comment: This is not possible: `{1..$1}`. Brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

Comment: Is that specific to `go`? Also, I think that a look at the process tree would help you. ;)

Comment: @Cyrus: Try it, it assumes that `$1` evaluates to a number.

Comment: @Cyrus - based on your comment, I updated it to `for ((i=0;i<=$1;i++))` and that seems to work. I'd be interested in knowing the full explanation though.

Comment: It has nothing to do with go, but with the bash script. The bash interpreter first expands the {1..$1} part, it assumes you meant {1..1}, then it replaces $1 with the value you provided, but it is already too late, since bash rewrote {1..$1} to {1..1}.

Comment: As first step bash tries to expand `{1..$1}`. `$1` is here only a string and bash can't expand `{1..$1}`. It remains `{1..$1}`. Then bash expands `$1` to `3` (e.g.) and now it gets `{1..3}`. Your loop runs only once while `$i` contains string `{1..3}`.

Comment: I suggest to replace `i=0` with `i=1` or replace `<=` with `<`.

Comment: This is also covered in [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).

Comment: The order of expansion is described by the bash manual: `PAGER='less +/^Expansion' man bash` and the online one: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html, although `{1..$n}` works in `zsh`